# missing return in a function expected to return swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make a button that makes the background switch between red and green but I get this error:

> missing return in a function expected to return UIView

I'm pretty new to coding, I've googled a bit but I didn't find anything.

Language:Swift

my code:

```
var timeLeft = 0
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var buttonColor: UIView! {

        timeLeft = 1
    }

    func update() {
        if timeLeft > 0 {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        }
        else {

            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
        timeLeft = timeLeft - 1

    }
}
```

thanks for helping

Comment: see the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689469/swift-error-missing-return-in-function

Answer (score 2):

You declare `buttonColor` as a computed property which in its body requires you to return a `UIView` instance (since its type is `UIView`).

Read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) or [here](http://www.codingexplorer.com/computed-properties-in-swift/) about computed property and make sure it fits your needs as posted in your case

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow

Remember to make an action connecting your UIButton to the code. Otherwise your code will not run when you click on the button. Also, consider using a Bool (true/false) variable to keep track of the background color.

Try the following code (remember to connect the 'click'-function to the button via the storyboard):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var isGreen = true

    @IBAction func click() {
        if isGreen {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            isGreen = false
        } else {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            isGreen = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var buttonColor: UIView! {
get() {
return (Object of UIView)
}
}