# How to randomly print a word in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

I have been trying to create an app that randomly prints a new word after a certain amount of time, i.e five seconds.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myTimer : Timer!
    var theValue = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var InspireLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.myTimer.invalidate()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @objc func updateMyLabel() {
        theValue += 1
        self.textLabel.text = String(theValue)
    }

    func randomText() -> String {
        if theValue > 5 {
            let words = ["Place", "Cat", "House"]
            return words.randomElement() ?? "" //Use default method to get random element from Array
        }
        return "string if theValue < 5 or equal to 5"
    }

    @IBAction func ResetButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.myTimer.invalidate()
        theValue = 0
        self.textLabel.text = String(theValue)
    }

    @IBAction func PauseButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.myTimer.invalidate()
    }

    @IBAction func PlayButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateMyLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
}
```

This is all the code I have right now. As you can probably tell I'm new too StackExchange and so please excuse any breach in etiquette.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift error: 'missing return in function'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689469/swift-error-missing-return-in-function)

Comment: Your edit now makes the whole question irrelevant and it makes the answers irrelevant. Please do not completely change your question after getting an answer.

Comment: I changed one thing to update that one part of the problem was solved? Hardly changed the whole question... @rmaddy

Comment: Your original question was about the error regarding the missing return. Your edit fixed that problem and added a new issue. I put back your original question since it has now been solved. You should accept the answer below since it solved your original question. If you now have a new issue, please post a new question with all relevant details as needed.

Comment: @rmaddy my original question was about how to make a random word generator IN GENERAL not one specific part that was wrong. Now would you please let me get a complete answer to my question *facepalm*

Comment: Do not edit your question to invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

it's giving an error because you forgot to add `else` part in your code.

```
func randomText() -> String {
    if theValue > 5 {
        let words = ["Place", "Cat", "House"]
        return words.randomElement() ?? "" //Use default method to get random element from Array
    }
    return "string if theValue < 5 or equal to 5"
}
```

Comment: thank you, however whilst it now runs, the text does not change

Comment: Better yet Array now has a `randomElement()` function

Comment: Answer Updated. :)

Comment: note that getting a random element out of only 3 elements the chance of getting the same element twice in a row is really high.

Comment: thank you very much, sadly it is still not working despite all your hard work (which I really appreciate) would you mind taking a look at the main question if I add a bit more to give a wider perspective? @LeoDabus